# Route view from google maps after running

Tags: android, image, google-maps

I'm making app similiar to Endomondo for school project. I'd like to draw the way I'm running on. So I used Google Maps Api for android. And the route is drawn. But I'd like to store it in my sqlite db and then show it for example in my history. I was thinking about taking a snapshot of the map but it isn't work when map is hidden (it's on the fragment that is hidden on the right) I also thougt about storing all the latlon points and then draw it on the map. What is the best way to save to route that I run with possibility to show it as image?

Comment: But my history will be a expandable list biew, so for each element I would have to add map fragment? So the memory will run out very fast...

Comment: I am talking about the direction api response